# How does Intel XDK's Cloud Build Work?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-build, intel-xdk

How does Intel XDK create a .apk and .ipa files on their cloud servers?

I know that they don't use Xcode or Android sdk on their cloud servers.

Is there any tool that takes www directory of cordova project and generates apk or ipa files?

I think even PhoneGap cloud build works similar way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, we do use Xcode and the Android SDK (and Visual Studio) on our cloud servers. The Intel XDK build servers are running a slightly modified version of standard Cordova CLI, which requires those native tools to complete a build. So the results you get from the Intel XDK are usually identical to what you would get if you used Cordova CLI locally.

There are a few differences at the front-end and back-end of the build process, that are needed to accommodate security of your account and to deal with the fact that the build is not occurring locally on your machine. Also, there are a few features of Cordova CLI that are disabled, mostly the infrequently used "hooks" features, in order to maximize security of the build servers.

There are some plugins that will not work with our cloud-based system, but the vast majority will.

If you use the [Early Access version of the XDK](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/561050) (the majority of the features from that version will be merged into the next major release of the XDK) you can use Cordova CLI locally with the Intel XDK project. You will have to build a config.xml file to make Cordova CLI work, but most of that can be taken from the intelxdk.*.xml files that are automatically generated by the XDK.